# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Raspberry Pi 's [second moderator election](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: jacobm001] [image: goobering]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Steve Robillard who has been a moderator [since the beginning](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), but is stepping down after this election. Thanks for your hard work helping this community achieve graduation and become a valuable resource on the network.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6237755176648704/0).

Comment: Congratulations guys.

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Thank you, but it's hard to believe you're stepping down! Take a vacation, and don't make yourself a stranger. :)

Comment: @MR.Mastel I will still be around, I don't plan to leave the site just need a little break I have been here since private beta and seeing the site through graduation and a second successful election has been an overwhelmingly positive experience. It was nice to see an election where fake news was not mentioned.

Comment: @SteveRobillard May I second the congratulations to the candidates and those elected and second the thanks to Steve for the great work he has done for the Raspberry Pi site,

Comment: Congrats and thank you for putting yourselves forward everybody. Much appreciated. @SteveRobillard - thank you for all your hard work!

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks so much for all your hard work over the years, and it's sad to see you stepping down. And congratulations to the new mods - you get my seal of approval. Best of luck to all three of you in the future!

Comment: Thank you all for your kind words.

Comment: Forgot to vote but good to see that my favorite candidates made it as moderators. Good luck *Jacobm001* and *goobering* - use your powers wisely :) And thanks to *SteveRobillard* for his work as a previous moderator!